# Получение цветов из RGB 24 bit

Tags: python, pillow

Имеется цвет в `RGB 24bit`, в таком виде `3.36855000e+006`. Требуется отрисовать изображения попиксельно. Рисую с помощью PIL, имея матрицу цветов в RGB 24bit, метод `point()` требует конкретно значение цвета R, G, B. Надо перевести значение цвета в биты, разбить по 8 бит, чтобы получить цвет. Хотя возможно я не правильно понимаю и это можно реализовать проще.

Вот код, где matrix хранит матрицу цветов вида приведенного выше

```
def create_image(matrix, path_safe):
 image = Image.new('RGBA', (64, 64))
 draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
 for ind_image in range(count_image):
    for y in range(size_matrix):
        for x in range(size_matrix):
            print(int(float(matrix[ind_image][y][x])))
            colorR = bin(int(float(matrix[ind_image][y][x])))
            colorG = bin(int(float(matrix[ind_image][y][x])))
            colorB = bin(int(float(matrix[ind_image][y][x])))
            draw.point((x, y),(colorR, colorG, colorB))
        y += 1

    image.save('test.png')
```

Comment: Кода бы с проблемой, чтобы можно было поиграться с ним

Comment: struct.unpack можно использовать чтоб достать из исходника побайтно r,g,b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так подойдет?

```
In [119]: rgb = 3.36855000e+006

In [120]: rgb = int(rgb)

In [121]: blue =  rgb & 255
     ...: green = (rgb >> 8) & 255
     ...: red =   (rgb >> 16) & 255
     ...:

In [122]: blue
Out[122]: 102

In [123]: green
Out[123]: 102

In [124]: red
Out[124]: 51
```

Comment: Да, спасибо все работает

Comment: почему вы выбрали от старшего к младшему порядок байт для RGB?

Comment: Выбирал не я) Мне уже препдоставили массив цветов

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы по одному пикселю цвета не вытаскивать, можно сразу все данные для картинки в списке картинок (`matrix`) в numpy массив превратить. Затем сохранить этот массив как картинку:

```
import numpy as np  # $ pip install numpy
from PIL import Image  # $ pip install pillow

def save_images(images_matrix, path_prefix):
    for i, image_data in enumerate(images_matrix, start=1):  # for each image
        arr = np.array(image_data, np.dtype(('<i4', ('u1', 4))))  # rgba
        img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGB')
        img.save(path_prefix + str(i) + '.png')
```

где `images_matrix` список, к примеру, равен:

```
nimages, (width, height) = 10, (64, 64)
images_matrix = [[[3368550]*width for _ in range(height)] for _ in range(nimages)]
```

это означает: `10` картинок размером `64x64`, где каждый пиксел имеет цвет: `(102, 102, 51)`:

```
>>> color = 3368550
... for place, color_name in zip(range(3), "RGB"):
...     print(color_name, (color >> 8*place) & 0xFF)
...     
R 102
G 102
B 51
```

Обратите внимание: цвета в этом примере от младшего байта к старшему хранятся.